# Flutter how to save each key value receive from rest API to different shared preference value be it string or int

Tags: arrays, flutter, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Can anyone help with how I can get these this array of objects saved in shared preferences with flutter? I created a JSON rest API that returns the below array of an object:

```
[{
    "first_name": "firstname",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "profile_pic": "user.png",
    "designation_id": "33",
    "department_id": "2",
    "employee_id": "175",
    "level": "hr",
    "dept_code": "HR",
    "email": "email.com",
    "user_id": "1"
}]
```

Am looking for a workaround on how to save each key value to a shared preference and reuse it.
For example save `"first_name", "last_name"...` below is how am receiving my JSON:

```
final String baseUrl = "http://xxx/login.php";
    var response;
    Client client = Client();

Future<bool> createProfile(LoginProfile data) async {
      response = await client.post(
        "$baseUrl",
        headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
        body: loginProfileToJson(data),
      );

    }

var resBody = json.decode(response.body); 
String array = resBody.toString(); 
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
prefs.setString('array', array);
```

With the above, it is not receiving the value separately but together and I want to have each value saved individually to reuse for example:

```
prefs.setString('firstname', first_name);
prefs.setString('lastname', last_name);
prefs.setString('level', level);
prefs.setString('deptcode', dept_code)... and so on.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
Step 1: You can pass `Map`'s `key` and `value` to `Function setData` 
Step 2: Use `jsonMap.forEach((k, v) => setData(k, v));` to do for loop 
Step 3: `key` has `underline` like `first_name` not `firstname` , but you can in `setData` remove `underline`

code snippet

```
  setData(String k, String v) async {
     await prefs.setString(k, v);
  }

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String jsonString = ...;

    var resBody = json.decode(jsonString);
    Map jsonMap = resBody[0];
    jsonMap.forEach((k, v) => setData(k, v));

    print(prefs.getString("first_name"));
    print(prefs.getString("dept_code"));
```

output

```
I/flutter ( 6692): firstname
I/flutter ( 6692): HR
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  setData(String k, String v) async {
    await prefs.setString(k, v);
  }

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String jsonString = '''
    [{
    "first_name": "firstname",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "profile_pic": "user.png",
    "designation_id": "33",
    "department_id": "2",
    "employee_id": "175",
    "level": "hr",
    "dept_code": "HR",
    "email": "email.com",
    "user_id": "1"
}]
    ''';

    var resBody = json.decode(jsonString);
    Map jsonMap = resBody[0];
    jsonMap.forEach((k, v) => setData(k, v));

    print(prefs.getString("first_name"));
    print(prefs.getString("dept_code"));

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to run a loop on your map and you will get the property and name of each key-value pair, try this out.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    "first_name": "firstname",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "profile_pic": "user.png",
    "designation_id": "33",
    "department_id": "2",
    "employee_id": "175",
    "level": "hr",
    "dept_code": "HR",
    "email": "email.com",
    "user_id": "1"
};
  
  data.forEach((k, v) {
// set prefrence values here
 data.forEach((k, v) => print("Key : $k, Value : $v"));
});

}
```